# UWP:Uncheck checkboxes inside ListView on Button Click Event

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am trying to clear selected checkbox inside popup=>ListView on Button Click Event.

I have tried looping listview and setting property to false but it is not working.

```
<Page
    x:Class="UC.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UC"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:mvsc="using:UC.Models"
    
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="btn_Add" Content="Add"  Margin="420,10,10,0" Click="Btn_Add_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="10,50,10,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Selected List" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1"  Margin="10,0,800,5" Height="300">
                <ListView  x:Name="lstViewSelectedData" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="mvsc:SelectedDataModel">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="txtSelectedData" Text="{x:Bind Message}"></TextBlock>
                                <AppBarButton VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="AppBarButton_Click" Icon="Delete" 
                                      Tag="{x:Bind Id, Mode=OneWay}" >
                                </AppBarButton>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </Border>

        </StackPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="popup1" VerticalOffset="10" HorizontalOffset="450" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                    Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1" Width="450" Height="400" >
                <StackPanel x:Name="stkpnl1" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Header="Filter" Margin="10"  
                         PlaceholderText="Search list" TextChanging="TxtSearch_TextChanging" />


                    <ListView x:Name="lstView" Margin="30" Height="200" 
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="mvsc:SelectedDataModel" >
                                <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" 
                                        
                              FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  
                              Tag="{x:Bind Id, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              Content="{x:Bind Message, Mode=TwoWay}" IsChecked="{x:Bind IsFavorite,Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Checked="ChkBox_Checked" Unchecked="ChkBox_Unchecked" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" >
                        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Select" Click="BtnAdd_Click" Margin="10" />
                        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Close"  Click="BtnCancel_Click"/>


                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public SelectedDataModel SelectedData
        {
            get { return (SelectedDataModel)GetValue(SelectedDataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedDataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDataProperty =
                        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedData", typeof(int), typeof(SelectedDataModel), null);

        public AllDataModel AllDataList
        {
            get { return (AllDataModel)GetValue(AllDataListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AllDataListProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AllDataListProperty =
                        DependencyProperty.Register("AllDataList", typeof(int), typeof(AllDataModel), null);

        List<SelectedDataModel> listData = new List<SelectedDataModel>();
        List<SelectedDataModel> temp = new List<SelectedDataModel>();
        List<SelectedDataModel> temp1 = new List<SelectedDataModel>();
        List<SelectedDataModel> selectedData = new List<SelectedDataModel>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            lstView.ItemsSource = GetData();
            //lstViewSelectedData.ItemsSource = GetSelectedData();
            temp = listData;
        }
        public List<SelectedDataModel> GetData()
        {
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 1, Message = "One" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 2, Message = "Two" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 3, Message = "Three" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 4, Message = "Four" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 5, Message = "Five" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 6, Message = "Six" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 7, Message = "Seven" });
            listData.Add(new SelectedDataModel { Id = 8, Message = "Eight" });

            return listData;
        }

        private async void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedData.Count == 0)
            {
                ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
                dialog.Title = "Not Selected";
                dialog.Content = "Please Select Atlease One Entry";
                dialog.CloseButtonText = "Close";
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                lstViewSelectedData.ItemsSource = null;
                var dt = selectedData;
                lstViewSelectedData.ItemsSource = dt;
                //this.selectedData.ForEach(x => x.IsFavorite = false);
                //this.listData.ForEach(x => x.IsFavorite = false);
                //temp1 = dt;
                popup1.IsOpen = false;



                //foreach (SelectedDataModel row in lstView.Items.ToList())
                //{
                //    //CheckBox box = row.FindName("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
                //    if (row.IsFavorite == true)
                //    {
                //        row.IsFavorite = false;
                //      //  listData.Remove(listData.First(X => X.Id == row.Id));
                //        //Logic to delete the row 
                //    }

                //}
                for (int i = 0; i < lstView.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)lstView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lstView.Items[i]);

                    if (lvi != null)
                    {
                        //CheckBox c = lvi.FindChildByType<CheckBox>();
                        //c.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        private void TxtSearch_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            listData = temp;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                listData = listData.Where(x => x.Message.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper())).ToList();
                if (listData.Count > 0)
                {
                    lstView.ItemsSource = listData;
                }
                else
                {
                    lstView.ItemsSource = temp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lstView.ItemsSource = temp;
            }
        }
        private void ChkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            //throwing an exception System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
            selectedData.Add(listData.First(x => x.Id == int.Parse(chkBox.Tag.ToString())));
           // listData.Remove(listData.First(X => X.Id == int.Parse(chkBox.Tag.ToString())));

            //selectedData.Clear();


        }


        private void ChkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            selectedData.Remove(listData.First(X => X.Id == int.Parse(chkBox.Tag.ToString())));

        }
        private void BtnAddData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //popup2.IsOpen = false;
            popup1.IsOpen = true;
        }
        private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            popup1.IsOpen = false;
        }
        private void Btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            popup1.IsOpen = true;
        }
        private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AppBarButton delButton = sender as AppBarButton;
            ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
            dialog.Content = "Do You Want To Remove..?";
            dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Yes";
            dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "No";
            dialog.Title = "Remove";
            ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
            if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            {
                //var isRemoved = temp.Remove(listData.First(x => x.id == int.Parse(delButton.Tag.ToString())));

                //List<Info> temp1 = new List<Info>();
                //foreach (var item in temp)
                //{
                //    temp1.Add(item);
                //}
                //lstViewSelectedData.ItemsSource = temp1;
                var temp2 = selectedData;
                temp2.Remove(temp1.First(x => x.Id == int.Parse(delButton.Tag.ToString())));
                lstViewSelectedData.ItemsSource = null;
                lstViewSelectedData.ItemsSource = temp2;
            }
        }

    }
```

I just want to clear checked items inside listview on button click event UWP.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried looping listview and setting property to false but it is not working.

Your CheckBox bound to the `IsFavorite` property. So, if you want to make it unchecked, you just need to updated the value of the `IsFavorite` property. To make the UI update when the property's value is changed, your `SelectedDataModel` class need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged).

```
public class SelectedDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set
        {
            if (_Id != value)
            {
                _Id = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Message;

    public string Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set
        {
            if (_Message != value)
            {
                _Message = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Message"));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsFavorite;

    public bool IsFavorite
    {
        get { return _IsFavorite; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsFavorite != value)
            {
                _IsFavorite = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsFavorite"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then, in your button click event handler, you just need to change each item's IsFavorite to false in `listData`.

```
foreach (var item in listData)
{
    item.IsFavorite = false;
}
```